# Outlook 2010 and Python email smtplib - info in proper fields

Tags: python, sendmail, python-2.6, outlook-2010, smtplib

When trying to send mail through Outlook 2010 with **smtplib** in Python 2.6.5, I at least encounter success sending the message, but *s.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)* is not putting the information in the From:, To:, and Subject: lines for me.

I need to know how to send email using smtplib in Outlook 2010 properly so that the email is received with the From:, To:, and Subject: fields on the message filled in.

Here is my code. I googled to find this framework:

```
import smtplib

SERVER = 'mail.company.com'
FROM = 'jdoe@company.com'
TO = ['receiver1@company.com']
SUBJECT = "Test Subject SMTP"
TEXT = "If this is in the body of the email, test is a success!"

message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n
%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)



try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    s.sendmail(FROM, TO, message) # this line is not correctly putting info in proper fields for Outlook 2010
    s.quit()
    print "Successfully sent email."

except:

    import sys, traceback

    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "An error occurred on line " + str(tb.tb_lineno)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Output is that the email is successfully sent. And it is. Just not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Try s.set_debuglevel(1) to check what is going on.

The code looks ok.

You may be rejected on SMTP:

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'example@amail.com': (550, b'5.7.1 Unable to relay')}
```